# how do i say that a feature is only available on a given platform

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I know how to say that a dependancy is only needed on windows but how do I say (as a crate writer) that a feature is only available on windows.

I tried (based on the depends way)

```
[target.'cfg(windows)'.features]
windbg = []
```

but this doesn't work.

cargo build says

```
warning: unused manifest key: target.cfg(windows).features
```

and a client app using the crate fails saying that the feature doesn't exist

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to do, if it is not possible you may try to hack with defining your feature like this `windbg = ["winapi"]` . this will make your feature depends on a crate that has been defined for windows targets.

Comment: nope, the github CI is still trying to build it when it does ubuntu build

Comment: i guess I should get me a linux box :-)

Comment: Please try replacing `#[cfg(feature = "windbg"] ` attributes with `#[cfg(all(target_os = "windows", feature = "windbg"))]`

Comment: @ÖmerErden ok, that worked, still stupid that you cannot simply say, this feature only works on windows

Comment: I am not sure if there is any request for this problem, this is the closest thing i've found : https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1197#issuecomment-268203727 . For the Linux, you may try vagrant, once you initiate, it can be very useful to do quick builds for different platforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Cargo is not able to specify feature's target platform, but you can add `target_os` to your code as an extra attribute to let compiler know that your feature will only be available on the target you set.

Let's say you have defined your feature like below.

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "windbg")]
mod windbg {
    //...
}
```

You'll need to replace it with:

```rust
#[cfg(all(target_os = "windows", feature = "windbg"))]
mod windbg {
    //...
}
```

Comment: and I installed rust on my trusty little pi -)